# Как скрыть окно в Windows xp при запуске (не cmd) на VBS

Tags: vbscript, всплывающее-окно, autoit

OS: Windows XP sp3 x32

Есть программка - [dtr8x.exe](http://radiofid.ru/upload/files/terminals/irz_terminals/dtr8x.rar)
на сайте
[ссылка на Faq](http://faq.radiofid.ru/topics/36-apparatnyij-perezapusk-modemov-watchdog-tajmer-irz-mc52it-mc52iwdt-i-irz-mc52pu/)

которая реализуется путём восьмикратного поднятия-опускания сигнала DTR в течение заданного времени. Рекомендуемые значения: 0.5 сек импульс, 0.5 сек пауза.

Программа запускается в виде окна

как скрыть окно, чтобы процесс запускался в фоновом режиме через vbs

пробовал в интернете скрипты

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "dtr8x.exe", 0
```

не работают, запускают скрытно только cmd (консольные приложения)

подскажите код на vbs который скроет окно программы, чтобы я просто вставил полный путь программы, и оно его скрыло, и обратите внимание программа запускается с ключем "/1"
путь:

```
c:\teset\dtr8x.exe /1
```

Comment: Добавить его (батник) в Планировщик задач и запускать от системного пользователя (в не интерактивном режиме). Тогда точно никакое окно не будет видно.

Comment: никаких аутоит, исключено, только штатные средства винды

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример на VBS (не совсем понятно чем это решение не устраивает)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "c:\dtr8x.cmd" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Или вот относительно простое (но более функциональное) решение на [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/):

```
#include <WinAPIProc.au3>

$aWin = winlist()       ; получаем массив всех открытых окон

for $i=0 to Ubound($aWin) - 1
   $hwnd = $aWin[$i][1]
   $pid = WinGetProcess($hwnd)      ; получаем PID процесса
   $path = __WinAPI_GetProcessFileName($pid)  ; получаем полный путь к exe   
   if StringInStr($path,"cmd.exe") then  ; ищем нужный файл
      consolewrite($path & @CRLF)
      WinSetState($aWin[$i][1], "",@SW_HIDE)
      ExitLoop
   EndIf
next

Func _WinAPI_QueryFullProcessImageName($hProcess)
    Local Const $PROCESS_NAME_NATIVE = 1
    Local $dwSize = 65535
    Local $aRet = DllCall("kernel32.dll", "BOOL", "QueryFullProcessImageName", "handle", $hProcess, "dword", 0, "str", "", "dword*", $dwSize)
    Return $aRet[3]
 EndFunc

Func __WinAPI_GetProcessFileName($PID = 0)
    If Not $PID Then $PID = @AutoItPID
    Local $hProcess = DllCall('kernel32.dll', 'handle', 'OpenProcess', 'dword', __Iif($__WINVER < 0x0600, 0x00000410, 0x00001010), _
            'bool', 0, 'dword', $PID)
    If @error Or Not $hProcess[0] Then Return SetError(@error + 20, @extended, '')
    Local $Path = _WinAPI_QueryFullProcessImageName($hProcess[0])
    Local $iError = @error
    DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "CloseHandle", "handle", $hProcess[0])
    If $iError Then Return SetError(@error, 0, '')
    Return $Path
EndFunc   ;==>_WinAPI_GetProcessFileName
```

Здесь есть нюанс, что у файла .cmd путь процесса будет `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, а путь к вашем файлу будет в параметрах командной строки как `cmd /c ""C:\dtr8x.cmd" "`

Comment: 1 вариант не работает! он только для cmd\bat скриптов командной строки, тут же приложение. и я поправил тему, там в коде было указано dtr8x.cmd - а это приложение windows dtr8x.exe

Comment: @Anatoly, почему вы решили, что для exe не работает? Попробуйте `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "notepad.exe" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing`

Comment: Потому что не работает, это было сказано в теме. окно windows не закрывается после выполнения операции. все это уже протестировано, вы можете скачать и убедиться сами.

Answer (score 0):

На **AutoIt** v3

```
#NoTrayIcon; не показать иконку в панель задач
$ProcessPath = "C:\dtr8x.exe" ;место где находиться .exe - файл
Run($ProcessPath, Default, @SW_HIDE); @SW_HIDE - скрыть окно
```

*Удачи!*